# jsplumb disable adding the class

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, jsplumb

I use jsPlumb library and I run into problem: in object $(".#{instance_id}") added class **_jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_**. How disable adding class to this object?

My code on coffee script:

```
jsPlumb.connect
  source: port_id
  target: instance_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Such `_jsPlumb_` classes are used by `jsPlumb` internally for management, there is no usual way to disable it, since it might affect the functionality.

A good alternative is to add your own class on top of `jsPlumb` defaults to control what you need, or just add CSS for the class added by `jsPlumb`

Reference :

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/styling-via-css

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/anchors.html#css

https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/defaults.html - Change the defaults.